# AdSense approval

Tags: vue.js, admob, nuxt.js, adsense

I'm about to release my pwa, but before that I would like to add adsense ads. However, I'm having problems in getting my site approved. I'm getting the "No content" policy violation. A little bit of background:

My site is not a blog, is an online Fitness tool. I have my landing pages with features, about, contacts, terms and privacy. The rest of the app is behind a login screen. The app was built with **springboot** as backend and **vue** + **nuxt** as frontend. Nuxt is configured to be an spa.

After digging on the web, I found out that the crawler is not able to see my page because is not SSR. And I found some people on the web who are serving the pages as SSR for the crawlers, while as SPA for the actual users. Is that possible using nuxt + vue? Will this solve the issue?

Alternatively I can take a different ads broker like media.net, may I ask if anyone had good and successful experience with it?

Another alternative is to wrap my app with Cordova and deploy it as an android/ios apk and apply for admob (but I dont really like this solution).

Comment: Yeah, don't wrap it inside of Cordova please. This may be the easiest/most effective solution if you want to keep an SPA while still being able to deliver the website in a pre-rendered way: https://prerender.io/ Not sure if it will actually solve any issue tho.

Comment: make sure the reason for the no content is what you think it is before fixing, google crawl my SPA sites all the time with no issues

Comment: Thank you @kissu for your suggestion, I will do some more verification before moving to preprender.

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceCherone for you reply, I hope this is the issue. But Im afraid it has to do also with the nature of my app. Can I ask you what kind of spa you have?

Comment: An SPA is an SPA, there is no specific type. It being behind an auth page, may be the issue here.

Comment: Hi Kissu, I was asking about the content of his SPA, whether it is a blog, tool, game, etc.. Well, to be honest is not really behind an auth page, the pages are accessible but all my api requests require authentication (if token is not present or refreshing the token do not work, the user is redirected to the login page).

Comment: I saw the crawler can be configured with username and password, maybe I can try to set up a mock user for adsense and give him the credentials.

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem and I have no idea how to fix this, but if I open my site on a text browser, which is what the crawler see, nothing is loaded...

Comment: Ok looks like it has to do with nuxt ssr. At the moment is only SPA, but nuxt can be universal. Maybe, by setting it as ssr, the crawler will be able to see my pages.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I currently have a similar setup. 2 public facing pages and the rest behind auth. Adsense saying its "without content/low value content".

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, just add main page that describes your app and explains what it does. Some kind of landing page.